# unable to create a MySQL database with PHP on server?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cpanel

I am just trying to create database using PHP but not creating.It giving me following error :

```
Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost'
```

I am using **cPanel** ,where i created a user with all privileges & this user assigned to a specific database

I am working on *SaaS Application* (i.e. multiple database & single codebase).

Please help me to solve this problem.

Code I am using

```
   $dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
   $dbuser = 'xyz';
   $dbpass = 'xyz123';
   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   echo 'Connected successfully';

   $sql = 'CREATE Database test_db';
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not create database: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   echo "Database test_db created successfully\n";
   mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: your credentials do not match with database credentials. Check for username and password

Comment: it could be a permission issue. You may have to GRANT PRIVILEGES. I have had similar issues in postgres.

Comment: Gaurav that is not database issue bcoz i can fetch store data in connected database , my problem is i m not able create new database using same connection

Comment: Sam Orozco you are right.it could be permission issue but l granted all permission to the user while creating in cpanel & assigned it to specific database. Everything working right on localhost but not on cpanel server

Comment: Also, shift to MySQLi instead of MySQL because its deprecated.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).